# WebApi 2.0 - ApiControllers em outro Assembly não sofrem mapeamento se runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=“false”

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-2

Eu tenho uma aplicação *WebApi2* que implementa alguns *ApiControllers*.

Esta mesma aplicação referencia um *Assembly* que implementa alguns mais.

Todos estes *controllers* utilizam *Attribute Routing*, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
[RoutePrefix("sample1.endpoint")]
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage WebApiTest()
```

Se defino `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` no `web.config`, a aplicação funciona perfeitamente - mas eu quero desligar este atributo (que pode ser bastante custoso em produção).

Porém, se eu ajustar o valor de `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` para *false*, apenas os ApiControllers locais são corretamente mapeados; chamadas para os outros geram um `404`.

Qual parte, provavelmente óbvia, eu não implementei?

(cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376376/webapi-2-0-apicontrollers-in-another-assembly-fail-to-map-if-runallmanagedmodu)

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a [resposta nesta questão no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22506503/195417), o problema é que o módulo não está sendo carregado. Para isso basta chamar um método qualquer do módulo para poder garantir que o mesmo foi carregado, antes de chamar o `MapHttpAttributeRoutes`.

A resposta sugere que você crie o seguinte método na sua biblioteca externa:

```
public static class MyApiConfig {
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  }
}
```

E que se chame este método para registrar o módulo.

Você terá problemas caso existam vários módulos, pois ai o método `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` seria chamado várias vezes.

Se esse for o caso, pode criar um método que não receba nada, chamado `LoadModule`, cuja única operação vai ser algo que o compilador não possa resolver eliminar o método:

```
public static class MyApiConfig {
  public static Type LoadModule() {
      return typeof(MyApiConfig);
  }
}
```

Você deve chamar esse método, de cada módulo, antes de chamar o `MapHttpAttributeRoutes`.

Comment: Me parece ser o caminho. Testando neste exato momento, obrigado pela pronta resposta!

Comment: Depois me fala se deu certo.

Comment: @OnoSendai Você ainda está precisando de ajuda com isso?

Comment: Desculpe a demora no reply. A implementação inicial não funcionou, porém eu suspeito que os Controllers estejam sendo carregados no contexto OWin (utilizado por uma implementação SignalR paralela). Como ainda existe uma chance da sua resposta ser correta, eu gostaria de testar este cenário.